# Problems using JQuery Toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

Can anyone please help with this problem using JQuery Toggle? I have tried everything I can but just cannot get this to work.

Basically I have a menu with 2 levels of sub menu. The sub levels are hidden, until the main menu item is clicked. The problem is that when a main menu item is clicked, only 1 level of menu is then shown - level 2 never shows up. I have tried targetting these by class name, and varous other methods, but they simply refuse to show as I would expect them to. I have a JS fiddle below and would really appreciate some help.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

** update to post. Only the main menu items (class="mc") are responsible for toggling the menu. Sub menus are just links (which is why I target class="mc" only on click). Main menu items may not always have level 2 items.

JS FIddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Dunce/wdcwewhq/25/embedded/result/

```
<script>
$(function(){

 // hide all sub menu items on load.
$("#lhsNav ul").hide();

$('.mc','#lhsNav').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action

    //show or hide all sub menu items for selected main menu item
   $(this).nextAll().slideToggle();
    //$(this).next().slideToggle()
    //$(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
});

});
<script>
<ul id="lhsNav">
<li><a id="mc1" href="#" class="mc">Main Menu Item (Click To Toggle Sub  Menus)</a>
    <ul><li><a href="#" id="sc1"  class="sc1">Sub Menu Level 1</a>
            <ul><li><a href="#" id="sc2"  class="sc2">-> Sub Menu Level 2</a></li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>   
<li><a id="mc2" href="#" class="mc">Main Menu Item (Click To Toggle Sub  Menus)</a>
    <ul><li><a href="#" id="sc3"  class="sc1">Sub Menu Level 1</a>
            <ul><li><a href="#" id="sc4"  class="sc2">-> Sub Menu Level 2</a></li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>   
</ul>

<p>
This menu has 2 sub level categories - These are hidden on load.
</p>
<p>
    When a Main Menu item is clicked, the idea is to show all of the sub menu items (level 1 and level 2), that belong to that main menu. The problem is that only sub menu level 1 items are being shown. Sub menu level 2 items are never seen/toggled - why not? What am I doing wrong? I have tried alternative ways of targetting the elements, but nothing works.
</p>
```

Comment: the submenu's don't have the class `mc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only targetting element's with class `.mc` where are the sub menu's don't have that class. Instead you can target anchor elements within `li` which has a `ul` as its child

```js
// hide all sub menu items on load.
 $("#lhsNav .mc + ul").hide();

 $('a.mc', '#lhsNav').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action

   //show or hide all sub menu items for selected main menu item
   $(this).nextAll().slideToggle();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lhsNav">
  <li>
    <a id="mc1" href="#" class="mc">Main Menu Item (Click To Toggle Sub  Menus)</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="sc1"  class="sc1">Sub Menu Level 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="sc2"  class="sc2">-> Sub Menu Level 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a id="mc2" href="#" class="mc">Main Menu Item (Click To Toggle Sub  Menus)</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="sc3"  class="sc1">Sub Menu Level 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="sc4"  class="sc2">-> Sub Menu Level 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>

<p>
  This menu has 2 sub level categories - These are hidden on load.
</p>
<p>
  When a Main Menu item is clicked, the idea is to show all of the sub menu items (level 1 and level 2), that belong to that main menu. The problem is that only sub menu level 1 items are being shown. Sub menu level 2 items are never seen/toggled - why not? What am I doing wrong? I have tried alternative ways of targetting the elements, but nothing works.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I wasn't as clear as I should have been, sorry. Only the main menu items (class="mc") are responsible for toggling the menu. Clicking a main menu item should toggle ALL SUB MENU ITEMS. Jquery .nextAll(), in the context of the clicked main menu item should work, but it does not.

Comment: That's worked Arun thank you. I don't fully understand why this works, but I will study it until I do! Thank you for your help, which is very much appreciated.